# microsoft graph api sdk fails to retrieve user by principalname/email

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am getting the following error:

> Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
> Message: Resource 'xxxx@xxxx.net' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

I am trying to retrieve a user by email from my AD B2C tenant using the graph sdk like so:

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
{
    var clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(Globals.ClientId)
        .WithTenantId(Globals.TenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(Globals.ClientSecret)                
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientapp);

    return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
}



public static async Task<User> GetADUserAsyncByEmail(string email)
        {
            var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
            try
            {
                var user = await graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync();
                return user;
            }
            catch(ServiceException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            catch( Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: For which user email you are trying to get the details? Is it a personal account or Work account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the user you are trying to get corresponds to [consumer user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#consumer-user), if so it needs to be addressed by `issuer` and `issuerAssignedId` where:

- `issuer` is a B2C tenant name
- `issuerAssignedId`  is an email address of the user account

Example

```
var tenant = "{tenant-prefix}.onmicrosoft.com";
var signInName = "username@facebook.com"; 
        
var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{signInName}' and c/issuer eq '{tenant}')")
            .Select("displayName,id,userPrincipalName")
            .GetAsync();

 var foundUser = users.FirstOrDefault();
```

[Refer an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-get-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name) from official documentation

Comment: tried it with another user, now it returns null! Man this graph api is difficult to work with...